# What does this CURL error #7 mean?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get video stream information from justin.tv

I followed the code on wiki and ran into some errors. After outputing some errors here is what I got.

Curl: Enabled

Fatal error: Curl failed with error #7: couldn't connect to host in /srv/disk/14779/www/blah/test.php on line 30

Can anyone help me? I believe I did everything correctly, the URL surely works, I've checked.

```
   <?php
    $streamer = array();
    $status = array();
    $viewers = array();
    $i = 0;
    $stream_list = "jojo0123"; 
    echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
    try{
        $mycurl = curl_init();

        if (FALSE === $mycurl)
            throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

        curl_setopt ($mycurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($mycurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $url = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=" . $stream_list; 
        curl_setopt ($mycurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=jojo0123");
        $web_response =  curl_exec($mycurl); 


        if (FALSE === $web_response)
            throw new Exception(curl_error($mycurl), curl_errno($mycurl));
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    echo " web response: " . get_class($web_response) . "\n";
    $array = json_decode($web_response);

    echo "SIZE OF ARRAY IS                        " . sizeof($array) . "\n";
    foreach($array as $value) {
        $streamer[$i] = $value->channel->login;
        $viewers[$i] = $value->channel_count;
        $status[$i] = "online";
        $i++;
    }

    $data['streams'] = $streamer;
    $data['status'] = $status;
    $data['viewers'] = $viewers;
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: " couldn't connect to host" means er well, just that

Comment: I understand that, any idea why? Why would justintv put non working examples to retrieve data?

Comment: i tested your code it works fine, you must have a firewall issue or a DNS issue

Comment: I'm hosting my website from http://www.biz.nf/ ,

do you think that site is blocked by justin tv or something?

Comment: yup, me to, no issues. free web hosting - you really do get what you pay for. yet so see a free host that's not utter crap

Answer (score 0):

This response means you have a firewall blocking the connection. The port being used depends on what module you are using. Check server configuration & firewall configuration on your side.