# Unable to communicate with *.roblox.com from PHP Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, roblox

I've done extensive testing, enabled verbose cURL logging (Leaves no logs, gives a generic cURL error #7), tried using the built in handlers through file_get_contents. (Also errored, see below) It seems no matter what if I attempt to request information from anything on the roblox.com domain from my app it gets errored before it can even try. I know it is not the distant end as multiple other sites are working fine aswell as I've used an alternate host to try the same communications that I'm doing with Google App Engine and it worked without any issue. At this point I can only conclude that Google has banned my app from communicating with the ROBLOX website without giving me any indication of any kind. If this is true, why is my app banned, and more importantly, why wasn't I alerted?

cURL output with verbose logging enabled:

> https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=christbru01
>   CURL Failed with error #7: 
>   CURL HTTP CODE #0
>   CURL INFO: 0

This is the code which generated these:

> syslog(LOG_DEBUG,(string)$newurl);
>   syslog(LOG_WARNING,'CURL Failed with error #'.curl_errno($s).": ".curl_error($s));
>   syslog(LOG_DEBUG,'CURL HTTP CODE #'.curl_getinfo($s,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
>   syslog(LOG_DEBUG,'CURL INFO: '.curl_getinfo($s,CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE));

file_get_contents output:

> file_get_contents(https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=Christbru01): failed to open stream: Connection error

This is the code which generated this:

> echo file_get_contents("link removed due to insufficient reputation");

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539509/what-does-this-curl-error-7-mean

Comment: I've looked at that, usually when the cURL errors it gives a message, which in that question was "couldn't connect to host" but in my issue I get no error reason, no error details, and even no cURL logs even when verbose logging is enabled, so I believe that it's more likely not to be related with that. Especially since the system is acting like there was no error, even though it gives an error #7 (no reason) and the request returns false (that the cURL failed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cURL in your instance by adding `google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"` to your `php.ini` file.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini

Comment: Already added the full cURL, plus this does not explain why the file_get_contents wouldn't work.
In the php.ini: 'extension = "curl.so"'